# Simulate Tic Tac Toe game using C language

Tags: c, game, tic-tac-toe

I made a **Tic Tac Toe** game using C. Here two players, **player1** and **player2**, can participate and play. Please rate my code and suggest improvements.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void board(char t[]);
int cheak(char T[]);

void main()
{
int i=0,n,r=100,p=1;
char TOT[9]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
char a='X';
for(;i<9;i++)
    {
    clrscr();
    board(TOT);
    printf("\n\n\n Player1=X\nPlayer2=O");
    printf(" \n player %d tern:-",p);
    printf("\nEnter number");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    TOT[n-1]=a;
    if(a=='X')
        {
        a='O';
        }
    else
        {
        a='X';
        }
    r=cheak(TOT);
    if(r==1)
        {
        clrscr();
        board(TOT);
        printf("\nPlayer 1 win");
        break;
        }
    if(r==2)
        {
        clrscr();
        board(TOT);
        printf("\nPlayer 2 win");
        break;
        }
    if(p==1)
        {
        p=2;
        }
    else
        {
        p=1;
        }
    if(i==8)
        {
        clrscr();
        board(TOT);
        printf("\n\nMatch Draw");
        break;
        }
    }
getch();
}
void board(char t[])
{
printf("_________________");
printf("\n|| %c || %c || %c ||",t[0],t[1],t[2]);
printf("\n|---------------|");
printf("\n|| %c || %c || %c ||",t[3],t[4],t[5]);
printf("\n|---------------|");
printf("\n|| %c || %c || %c ||",t[6],t[7],t[8]);
printf("\n|---------------|");
}

int cheak(char T[])
{
int i=0,n=0;
for(;n<3;n++)
    {
    if(T[i]=='X'&&T[i+1]=='X'&&T[i+2]=='X')
        {
        return 1;
        }
    i=i+3;
    }  

i=0;
for(n=0;n<3;n++)
    {
    if(T[i]=='X'&&T[i+3]=='X'&&T[i+6]=='X')
        {
        return 1;
        }
    i++;
    }
if(T[0]=='X'&&T[4]=='X'&&T[8]=='X')
    {
    return 1;
    }
if(T[2]=='X'&&T[4]=='X'&&T[6]=='X')
    {
    return 1;
    }

i=0;
for(n=0;n<3;n++)
    {
    if(T[i]=='O'&&T[i+1]=='O'&&T[i+2]=='O')
        {
        return 2;
        }
    i=i+3;
    }

i=0;
n=0;
for(;n<3;n++)
    {
    if(T[i]=='O'&&T[i+3]=='O'&&T[i+6]=='O')
        {
        return 2;
        }
    i++;
    }
if(T[0]=='O'&&T[4]=='0'&&T[8]=='O')
    {
    return 2;
    }
if(T[2]=='O'&&T[4]=='O'&&T[6]=='O')
    {
    return 2;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### `void main()` is not portable

Although it "works" in a lot of cases, the only two portable definitions of `main` are:

```
int main(void)
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

### Error checking

You don't check the return value of `scanf`.

This would be better:

```
if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
{
    fputs("Error; enter a number.", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE; /* entering a letter will cause infinite loop so error out here */
}
```

Note that `EXIT_FAILURE` requires `stdlib.h` to be included.

### Out-of-bounds write

If a user enters a `0` or a number greater than `9` in the `scanf` mentioned above, this line will write outside of the array bounds:

```
    TOT[n-1]=a;
```

This can cause a segmentation fault.

### Spelling

There are a couple spelling errors in this code:

> cheak -> check
>   tern -> turn

### Formatting

There are a few issues with formatting here; first of all, each line in a function should be indented by at least 4 spaces. In addition, you should put spaces after commas  in function calls, and around most (if not all) operators.

### Portability

Although `clrscr` and `getch` work with Windows and DOS, I would suggest simply removing `clrscr` and replacing `getch` with `getchar`. This makes your code portable to the point where it can run on most other systems.

### Non-descriptive variable names

At first glance, I don't know what `t`, `T`, `TOT`, `a`, `i`, `n`, `r`, or `p` are for. The variable names should describe what they contain.

### Spacing

Although the board is nice, the prompt to the user isn't. I would suggest something like this:

```
    printf("\n\n\nPlayer 1 = X\nPlayer 2 = O");
    printf("\nPlayer %d's turn.",p);
    printf("\n\nEnter a number: ");
```

...

```
    if(r == 1 || r == 2)
    {
        board(TOT);
        printf("\nPlayer %d wins!", r);
        break;
    }
```

### Misc.

`p` is already 1 here. You don't need to set it again:

```
    else
        {
        p=1;
        }
```